# Generating Excel file from database using Blazor page

Tags: c#, excel, blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

so I just recently started working in Blazor. I have my page set-up and I have successfully connected it with a database, in which I am gonna store some data. Now I am trying to generate an Excel file from these data, but I really struggle to find any information on how to properly do it. For now I load all the data from database to list, when the page loads. The goal is to add a button that will generate .xlsx or .csv file from this list and fire a download. Any suggestions how to do it? All help is appreciated.

Comment: If the user isn't editing the data in the UI then have a standard ASP MVC controller on your server that returns the file. In your Blazor app you can then navigate to that URL using `NavigationManager.NavigateTo` with `forceLoad` set to true.

Comment: PS: To the person who voted to close this question - could you please also comment and explain why?

Comment: You can add the EPPLus package. Creating an Excel was one of the first demos I saw.

Comment: @PeterMorris Thanks for suggestion Peter, gonna give it a shot.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Is it possible you could still have a link/source for that demo? Thanks in advance.

Comment: But some Blazor syntax is outdated now, it's moving fast. Just google for EpPlus.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yeah, I noticed that. Blazor is developing pretty fast. But it definitely caught my interest more than anything else, when it comes to web application development. Thanks again for the info :)

Comment: When you think about EPPlus, keep in mind that the current version 5 is no longer open source. Maybe CloseXML is an alternative.